# Why can't I make my div 100% height if I use an HTML5 doctype? How do I get it 100% height

Tags: css, html, quirks-mode

I am working on getting the layout sorted for a pretty simple gallery webapp, but when I use an HTML5 doctype declaration, the height of some of my divs (which were 100%) get shrunk right down, and I can't seem to plump them back up using CSS.

My HTML is at https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16178847/eyewitness/b/index.html and css is at https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16178847/eyewitness/b/style.css

- If I remove the HTML5 doctype declaration, all is as I want it to be,
  but I really want to use the proper HTML5 doctype declaration.
- If I set the doctype to HTML5 and make no changes, the div with the photo and the footer divs are not visible, presumably because they are 0px high.
- If I set the doctype to HTML5 and make the `body { height: 100px }` and `.container { height: 100px }` or `.container { height: 100% }`, it becomes visible, but what I need is it to be is full height rather than a height in pixels.
- If I try to do the same as above, but with the `body { height: 100% }` the photo and footer divs are not visible again.

What do I need to do to get it 100% in height so that my photo and footer divs are full height?

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML5 or CSS3. (What happens with any other doctype? Since when was `height` a new CSS3 thing?)

Comment: When you make the body 100% height, what are you expecting it to be 100% of?

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for your comment. That's a fair point about CSS3, I have removed that tag. I haven't tried any other doctypes, I have only tried it with no doctype or the HTML5 doctype. What are you hoping to figure out from the behaviour with other doctype declarations? I am more than happy to try a few and report back, but am unsure which ones would be relevant to try?

Comment: @robertc I was expecting it to be 100% of the viewport, presumably that is not how it works, but I don't know how to get that effect any other way.

Comment: Here's an explanation of the DOCTYPE issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32215263/3597276

Comment: Here's an explanation of the CSS `height` property with percentage values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728022/why-is-the-height-property-with-percentage-value-not-working-on-my-div/31728799#31728799

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Only if the parent element has a defined height, i..e not a value of `auto`. If that has 100% height, the parent's parent height must be defined, too. This could go until to the `html` root element.

So set the height of the `html` and the `body` element to `100%`, as well as every single ancestor element of that element that you wish to have the `100%` `height` in the first place.

See this example, to make it clearer:

```css
html, body, .outer, .inner, .content {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This wouldn't work, if I didn't give 100% `height` to—say `html` element:

```css
body, .outer, .inner, .content {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

… or `.inner`

```css
html, body, .outer, .content {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So are you saying that (in standards mode) there is no way of making a page the same height as the viewport (without using javascript to set a height in units rather than percentage)?

Comment: I'k saying you can. Give html element 100% height, give body element 100% height and so on with every child element of the body and the child elements of that element until you reach the element that you want to be 100% in the first place.

Comment: That is exactly the solution, I had no idea you could apply CSS to the html element. Nice one!

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, to make it work do as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Vertical Scrolling Demo</title>
  <style>
    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: white;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
    .page {
      min-height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="nav" class="page">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="page1" class="page">
    <h1><a name="about">about</a></h1>
    About page content goes here.
  </div>
  <div id="page2" class="page">
    <h1><a name="portfolio">portfolio</a></h1>
    Portfolio page content goes here.
  </div>
  <div id="page3" class="page">
    <h1><a name="contact">contact</a></h1>
    Contact page content goes here.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck into a similar problema to size a canvas, so here is what i did and worked perfectly.

Besides doing the:

```
body{ width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

Set the desired element like this:

```
.desired-element{ width: 100vw; height: 100vh}
```

In that way you are assured to have 100% of the view port in width and height.
vw stands for viewwidth
and
vh stands for viewheight

I hope this helps someone

Comment: When viewport units is used, one doesn't need to set any height to any other element, in this case the `body`.

Comment: In my case ag-grid was not taking height in `%` so applied height in `vh`,  super and simple. Here is working `<ag-grid-angular
          style="width: 100%; height: 76vh;"></ag-grid-angular>` .  That is not relevant but helpful for me.

Comment: Hello, good to know it helped you somehow, sorry for the bad answer, I am trying my best. Since this answer, I have gained more experience in Canvas positioning and got some best practices.

Always set the canvas as {position: absolute} and throw it behind everything else with z-index if you want it to be your background.