# pdf.js not working with <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf.js

I'm using [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to preview a PDF doc in my page.

I't works perfectly without doctype on top of the page. But when I add it, the PDF viewer stops working.

My doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Where I call the viewer:

```
echo '<div id="pdfViewer">';
    include('pdf_viewer.php');
echo '</div>';
```

CSS style of the pdfViewer division:

```
#pdfViewer {
   margin: 10px;
}
```

How can I add the doctype declaration and still keep my viewer working?

Comment: I don't think this anything to do with pdf.js -- pages are not rendering since pdfViewer height is 0px. Probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871898/why-cant-i-make-my-div-100-height-if-i-use-an-html5-doctype-how-do-i-get-it-1 will help

Comment: YES, that's it. Thanks for your reply. 
I've set a height to the parent node.

Comment: If you want the reputation points, post your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Your site links are prompting for a login for me... and links without code are not good formats for Stack Exchange sites anyway, because of [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot). Please post your relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed that the parent didn't have a height.

see: [Why can't I make my div 100% height if I use an HTML5 doctype? How do I get it 100% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871898/why-cant-i-make-my-div-100-height-if-i-use-an-html5-doctype-how-do-i-get-it-1)

example:

```
#pdfViewer {height: 800px;}
```