# HTML wild doctype

Tags: html, css

So i got 2 files divCeption.html and styles.css with the following code :

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#d1 {
    background-color: #ff000a;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="d1"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code works and it does what it is suposed to do: show a red screen on the screen.
Ok, problem comes here, notice the `<!doctype html>`missing at the start of the HTML. If i place the doctype at the start of the HTML the page will come blank... Can anyone explain me why that doctype is giving troubles?

Comment: On which browser did you try ? It is possible that by default, depending on the "rendering mode", the HTML and BODY elements do not have any height and width if not present.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871898/why-cant-i-make-my-div-100-height-if-i-use-an-html5-doctype-how-do-i-get-it-1

Comment: `width` and `height` sets using percentage won't work if their parent element has no dimensions defined. The percentage here is in relation to the element's parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem, and I have solved it by adding

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

to my CSS code.

The reason for this, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871898/why-cant-i-make-my-div-100-height-if-i-use-an-html5-doctype-how-do-i-get-it-1), may be that when the browser is in standards mode the percentage height of an element depends on the height of its parent, and the relationship goes up to the `html` element; you can see it for yourself by inspecting the `html` element and noticing that it doesn't take up all the space on your screen.

Even better than adding the CSS lines above, you should use a [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to set the height and width of the `html` and `body` element :

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
   margin: 0;
}

#d1 {
   background-color: #ff000a;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   </head>
  
   <body>
      <div id="d1"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```