# ag-grid Height=100% collapsed

Tags: ag-grid

Locally ran [Basic AngularJS 1.x Example](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-data-grid/#gsc.tab=0), found out if `style="height: 100%;"` the grid collapsed into a horizontal line. Setting it to something else like 100px works.
Everything the same except my Angular is 1.5.0, and ag-grid v8.1.0.

```html
<div ng-controller="exampleCtrl">
  <div ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

JS is the same as the tutorial. Looks like a bug.

Comment: except you put the ag-grid div inside of a div that has 0 height... so 100% of 0 is 0. Give some height to your div that has the ng-controller or set the ag-grid inside of the body tag like the example has.

Comment: good point, how about this original: `<body ng-app="example" ng-controller="exampleCtrl">

    <div ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 100%;"></div>

</body>

</html>
`

Comment: @JarodMoser it shouldn't be the parent <div> as we do it all the time that is not to specify any height for any parent <div>, it supposed auto-expand unless there is a "fixed" attribute.

Comment: BTW, browser is FF 50.1.0

Comment: My original comment was based on this [width and height](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-width-and-height/#gsc.tab=0) portion of the ag-grid docs. I tried to recreate your issue running a local file, but was unable to reproduce. I tried with JSFiddle and plunkr, but those sites have more JS that are adjusting the HTML tag's height in the iframe and causing different magic to happen...

Comment: it's probably my end cz I'm getting the same for javaScript.

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution? I'm having the same problem? setting a height is fine, but if I set a fix height, I'm either getting a vertical scroll bar or have some empty space.

Comment: @AngelaPan No, but like I said below, make  <!DOCTYPE> attribute-free.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is almost certainly due to you having DOCTYPE html in your html file.

If you do, then you need to ensure that the grids container has a non-0 height to fill, otherwise it will appear as a flat line as you've found.

This is not an ag-Grid specific issue - it's a side effect of not having quirks mode in use.

The easiest thing for you to do is this:

```
<style>
    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

[This StackOverflow Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871898/why-cant-i-make-my-div-100-height-if-i-use-an-html5-doctype-how-do-i-get-it-1) explains the underlying issue pretty well

Comment: It tells why. Your solution didn't work until I cut out everything inside of <!DOCTYPE>, leave it attribute-less. This is my original `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Comment: That's interesting - thanks for the update. I'll have to take a look at that

Answer (score 15):

You shall try setting the autoHeight of the ag-grid, by **setting the DomLayout**.

**See the sample code below for angular.**

```
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    //The ag-grid is not enlarging based on the page height, 
    //so dynamically adjusting the height of the grid
    this.gridApi.setDomLayout("autoHeight");
}
```

For reference see this https://plnkr.co/edit/Jb1TD7gbA4w7yclU?preview

Comment: This worked for me, with the addition of  `(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"` in the grid html and removing the height option from the css.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this isn't quite the same thing as setting height to 100%: it fixes the problem of the grid being zero height, but it attempts to size the grid to its contents (and may incur a performance penalty for a large number of rows, since it tries to measure every row), instead of taking the full available height. See https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/grid-size/#grid-auto-height.

Answer (score 5):

```css
.ag-root-wrapper-body.ag-layout-normal.ag-focus-managed {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is good, but overlay conflicts with header now. Any solution to that?